# Locating resourcebundle when deploying on weblogic

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, weblogic-10.x

I am gettign the following error when attemptign to load the jsp,after deploying the spring application on weblogic:

```
javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: No message found under code 'label.firstname' for locale 'en_US'.
```

What am I doing wrong?

JSP:

```
<form:form method="post" action="add.html" commandName="contact">

    <table>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="firstname"><spring:message code="label.firstname"/></form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="firstname" /></td>
    </tr>
.....
</table> 
</form:form>
```

Spring context:

```
<bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="messages" />
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    </bean>
```

Web-app(war) structure

```
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
WEB-INF/
WEB-INF/classes/
WEB-INF/classes/messages_en.properties
WEB-INF/classes/org/
WEB-INF/classes/org/spring/
WEB-INF/classes/org/spring/controller/
WEB-INF/classes/org/spring/controller/ContactController.class
WEB-INF/classes/org/spring/dao/
WEB-INF/classes/org/spring/dao/ContactDAO.class
WEB-INF/classes/org/spring/dao/ContactDAOImpl.class
WEB-INF/classes/org/spring/entity/
WEB-INF/classes/org/spring/entity/Contact.class
WEB-INF/classes/org/spring/service/
.....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basename property is relative to war root (not classpath), hence you should put it on `<war_root>/messages_en.properties`. If you don't want the properties file to be served, it's better to put it on `<war_root>/WEB-INF/messages_en.properties` and set the basename property to `WEB-INF/messages`